# Single Word for a Bright Day after the Darkest Night

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

I was curious if there is one word to describe "Bright Day after the Darkest Night". I have heared a quote about this and liked so much that i wanted to find a single word for it so that it can be given to something some project, some room or anything So, I wanted to know a descent and presentable single word to call the "Bright Day after the Darkest Night"

Comment: why negative response?

Comment: You are expected to show evidence of your own research. Please take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: I am sorry but I did some research and googling but didn't found anything which satisfies my curiosity. So asked here

Comment: Do you mean "Bright Day after the Darkest Night" figuratively?

Comment: @J.Siebeneichler Yes if possible and if that exist in this beautiful language called English :)

Comment: Dawn means the start of a new day. The apparent redundancy in the  phrase *"Dawn of a new day"*, emphasises the contrast between the dark of the previous night and a new day that is bright with possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Enlightenment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Age_of_Enlightenment) was a period that followed the "dark" ages. It was named to capture the idea that the tools of science and reason were illuminating the dark times of authoritarianism and dogma. It's probably the closest single word that captures the concept you are interested in.

Comment: This one is also pretty interesting

Answer (score 3):

There is no single word for a bright day after an extraordinarily, or regular, dark night. You will have to illustrate the idea in a sentence. You could use some of the synonyms for "dawn" to help you craft the sentence. Thesaurus.com lists many synonyms for "dawn" at the following URL: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/dawn

Comment: I am asking for bit more help can you please suggest one phrase using this synonyms. :D

Comment: There is the (very well-known) phrase [*"the dawning of the day"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dawning_of_the_Day), taken from two Irish folk songs with the same name.  "And the morning light was shining bright at the dawning of the day."

Comment: @Mick although the day dawns just as much even if the night was barely dark at all.

Comment: @Spagirl This is true, but I can think of nothing better.

Comment: @Mick. I should have :-)ed. I think the problem is that the questioner is not much wiling to accept that there isn't a shorter, snappier way to express their concept, and they haven't told us why their own researches haven't satisfied their 'curiosity'. For all I know there is such a word, but I probably wouldn't know what it meant if I met it in the wild.

Comment: @Spagirl i am sorry to say opposite to you but i have researched too much and still was curious if this word exist in English since I am not great at English so not finding such word by my research was not the end as i was not much confident about it. I was still curious and created account here by filling up a pretty lengthy form and you will be amazed to know this account is created for the sole purpose of asking this tiny question. I think i have done enough for my curiousity. what i did? I would call it more than just research